# Convert string with escapes to one without

Tags: python, escaping

I'm working on a exercism.io exercise in Python where one of the tests requires that I convert an SGF value with escape characters into one without. I don't know why they leave newline characters intact, however.

`input_val = "\\]b\nc\nd\t\te \n\\]"
 output_val = "]b\nc\nd  e \n]"`

I tried some codecs and ats functions to no avail. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: [This exercism](https://exercism.io/tracks/python/exercises/sgf-parsing/solutions/38753957e550427ab519e560941621a4), for [Smart Game Format](https://www.red-bean.com/sgf/)? I can't see anything that resembles your input. ([Example SGF file](https://www.red-bean.com/sgf/examples/print2.sgf))

Comment: Amadan: yes, that's it. It is in the test file of that exercise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The purpose of your exercise is unclear, but the solution is trivial:

```
input_val.replace("\\", "").replace("\t", " ")
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Based on SGF text formatting rules, I also found a solution with re.sub. Let me know what you think if you have time.

Comment: There is no need for `re.sub` here. You cannot do better than `replace`.

Comment: I think the `\\[` is supposed to match the `\\]`. If there is a possibility of `\\` appearing between those codes, then this solution is not robust. Neither is using regex. I guess it's exercism's fault for not including a testcase to cover that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
def no_escapes(text):  # get text argument
    # get a list of strings split with \ and join them together without it
    text = text.split('\\')
    text = [t.split('\t') for t in text]
    text = [i for t in text for i in t]
    return ''.join(text)
```

It will first turn `"\\]b\nc\nd\t\te \n\\]"` into `["]b\nc\nd\te \n"]`. It'll then turn it into `[["]b\nc\nd", "e \n"]]`. Next, it'll flatten it out into `["]b\nc\nd", "e \n"]` and it'll join them together without anything between the strings, so you'll end up with `"]b\nc\nd  e \n]"`

Example:

```
>>> print(no_escapes('\\yeet\nlol\\'))
yeet
lol
```

And if you want it raw:

```
>>> string = no_escapes('\\yeet\nlol\\')
>>> print(f'{string!r}')
yeet\nlol
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice! Any idea how to convert the '\t' characters in the middle too?

Comment: The `'\t'`? What meaning does that do? I'll add that in too then :D

Comment: `print(f'{no_escapes('\\yeet\nlol\\')!r}')` is giving me SyntaxError's.

Comment: I think `print(repr(string))` is more explicit and readable... But it does work now.

Comment: Hmm, that's true :)

Answer (score 0):

After looking at SGF text value rules [here](https://www.red-bean.com/sgf/sgf4.html#text) which says, 'all whitespaces except line breaks become spaces,' I came up with this solution. It oddly doesn't say '\\' characters should be erased, though. Not sure if there's a cleaner way to do this?

```
s = '\\]b\nc\nd\t\te \n\\]'

r = re.sub(r'[^\S\n]', ' ', s).replace(r'\\', '')

print(r)
# ']b\nc\nd  e \n]'
```